# JSDoc type equal to member of array

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

Say I have an array of strings.

```
/** @type Array.<string> */
var possibleValues = ['a','b','c','d'];
```

I have a function that accepts a string, however I only want it to be equal to one of the members of `possibleValues`.

```
/**
 * It does nothing.
 * @param {string} input One of the members of `possibleValues`.
 * @returns {string} Same as your input, useless... or is it?
 */
function nothing(input) { return input; }
```

Is there a way in [JSDoc 3](http://usejsdoc.org/) I can explicitly set the type of the `input` parameter to one of the values of `possibleValues`?

Preferably I would like to reference the original array and not just list its members in the comment as I am likely to reuse it and it may be subject to change later.

Comment: I'm guessing based on your wording that the array is not changing at run time (otherwise I would not expect you to mention to "list its members" since a static list of values would be misleading), but I'm not 100% certain that I'm right.

Comment: @Louis It is not changing at runtime, by _"subject to change"_ I mean in future versions of the application.

Comment: May be the `@typedef` tag (http://usejsdoc.org/tags-typedef.html) could help you to reference it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `@enum` for this:

```
/**
 * @readonly
 * @enum {string}
 */
var possibleValues = {
    A: 'a',
    B: 'b',
    C: 'c',
    D: 'd'
};

/**
 * It does nothing.
 * @param {possibleValues} input Something descriptive...
 * @returns {string} Same as your input, useless... or is it?
 */
function nothing(input) { return input; }
```